# Is it possible assign constraint to rotation and position?

Tags: cesiumjs

There is city 100k poeple big. I want show my terrain (map layer + 3 buildings) from arbitral height (z value). Is it possible do it using builtin mechanism?

Comment: Are you trying to constrain the camera from getting below a specific height?

Comment: Below should be fine cos I must lower area of ground in particular view.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the clock and each tick ensure that the camera is in the "allowed area".

Every tick, check to see if the camera is not in the correct postion. If it is not, correct it.

Here is an example limiting the height of the camera, but the same pattern could be used to limit other aspects of position too.

Sandcastle: http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases&gist=c943ebc6b2d06b9a555584cd1e3f6a97

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

// the max height that should be allowed in meters
var MAX_HEIGHT = 4e6;

// each clock tick ensure the camera is in the right position
viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(function() {
    var curHeight = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(viewer.camera.position).height;
    var heightFromMax = curHeight - MAX_HEIGHT;

    // if the height of the camera is above the max, move the camera forward to ensure it is lower than the max
    if (heightFromMax > 0) {
        viewer.scene.camera.moveForward(heightFromMax);
        return;
    }
});
```